# Blazor Webassembly Core Hosted Base Href Case Sensitive

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am building a Blazor WebAssembly Core Hosted app. I have the following added to the header of the index.html file.

```
<base href="/app/ApplicationName/" />
```

When I navigate to the website https://somewhere.com/app/applicationname, I get the following error in the console of the browser:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 System.ArgumentException: The URI 'https://somewhere.com/app/applicationname' is not contained by the base URI 'https://somewhere.com/app/ApplicationName/'.
```

This application is hosted on an IIS 10 server. My questions are:

1. How do I make it case insensitive, AND
2. How do I make it not require a trailing slash

Comment: As far as I know and experimented trailing slash is not mandatory. 
So you can access it using https://somewhere.com/app/ApplicationName.

However, it is quite weird that it can be accessed using the same casing defined in base tag.

Don't know the reason, all other URLs can be accessed in the case-insensitvie way on the same IIS but it doesn't work in case of Blazor App.

Comment: follow it here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6818